# how to cherry-pick commits without messing up branch pull request relationships?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Cherry-picking commits creates new commits with the same content. If I cherry pick from `dev` branch into `test` branch by way of `dev-to-test` branch, then the commits which I cherry picked will be included in the next pull request from `dev` branch into `test` branch even though their content was already added into test branch.

For example:

current commits present in branches:

```
dev:  a-b-c-d-e-f
test: a-b-c
```

Then I cherry-pick and fast-forward:

```
dev:         a-b-c-d-e-f
test:        a-b-c-g(content of e)-h(content of f)
```

Then a new commit is added to dev:

```
dev: a-b-c-d-e-f-i
```

I want to achieve three things:

1. the next pull request from dev to test to only pick up commits
   `d-i`;
2. the history of test to look like `test: a-b-c-g-h-d-i`;
3. to be able to track the relationship of test to the commits `e-f`
   via history.

How can I achieve this? Or should I restructure the git workflow to prevent such things from happening?

Here is a real life example of this issue:

Here is a setup for pull request, commits in red box have already been cherrypicked to the target branch.

[image: Screenshot from Azure DevOps pull request setup dialogue.]

Here is the resulting history. In orange are the commits that come from cherrypick. In red are commits from the pull request. The red commits have no associated changes and repeat exactly the messages of the orange commits.

[image: Screenshot from Visual Studio git branch history.]

Here are the details of the completed PR request. It features these two commits, which should not be there, since the pull request does not apply the changes which those commits describe.

[image: History from Azure DevOps completed pull request.]

Comment: For point 2, how do you define "look like"? Cus from my pov, simply do a normal PR will give you a result that "look like" what you describe. What's wrong with this result?

Comment: If you're wronging having 2 extra copy of files, as if it waste some disk storage, then rest assure it won't. Files are tracked in form of pointers in commit.

Comment: @hackape I want to avoid this version of history: `test: a-b-c-g-h-d-e-f-i`. When I did my pull request, it showed specifically the commits whose content was already merged. Messy history and messy pull requests like this are what I'm trying to avoid. I realize quite well that this will not create duplicated files.

Comment: I still don't get what you think is wrong about a normal merge. What mess does it creates

Answer (score 1):

Current situation:

```
dev: a-b-c-d-e-f-i
test      \g-h
```

Normally send PR from dev to test then merge:

```
dev: a-b-c-d-e-f-i
test      \g-h----\j  # j = h+i
```

---

Here's how I would describe test branch after merged

```
test: a-b-c-g-h-j
```

- `r(j) = r(h)+r(i)` as of relation, since `j` is the child of 1st parent `h` & 2nd parent `i`.
- `c(j) = c(d)+c(i)` as of file content, `j` represent a file content state such that when diff against `h`, will be equal to `d` diff against `c` + `i` diff against `f`, en bref,

---

Now many git GUI softwares decide to show things in a linear list fashion, usually in reverse chronological order, like

```
dev: a-b-c-d-e-f-----i
test      \------g-h--\j
 | 
 V   # visually merged down to
     a-b-c-d-e-f.g.h.i-j
```

This representation is only visually linear, doesn't mean these commits are connected linearly. So what you see is a linear list of commits from many branches, not just `test` branch in your example. `test`'s own history is fine, only has `g-h`, not `e-f`.

If you really want only one pair of `g-h` or `e-f` to show up, well, since this is a list of commits of all branches in repo, one of the pair need to be vanished from the repo. In other word, you need to rewrite history of either `dev` or `test` branch.

A couple of git commands can do such rewrite, `reset`, `rebase`, `filter-branch`.

Comment: I just created a branch to test this. Here is a [screenshot of pull request setup](https://i.imgur.com/7pMnb3W.jpg). Highlighted in red the commits whose content has been already merged by cherrypick. Then I made a pull request from the source branch, [and here is the resulting history](https://i.imgur.com/lVoB70u.jpg). Cherrypicked in orange. Red are commits from PR, they have no associated changes, they duplicate the previous commits' messages. Two problems here: 1) pull request details show these commits. 2) history has two empty commits with messages that are identical to other commits.

Comment: @Nomenator But you don't simply say such commits history belongs to `test` branch, nor should you imply the `a-b-c` chainup relationship. You show me a screenshot of some GUI's display. It's this software's decision how to *list* these commits in linear ordering, doesn't necessarily say, such commit is linearly traceable from the current ref of `test`.

Comment: @Nomenator in CLI, if you type `git rev-list --first-parent test` you see different thing

Comment: @Nomenator Now if you really want only one of  `e-f` or `g-h` pair to show up in that screenshot GUI, then one of the branch `dev` or `test`, has to be re-written so to remove 2 commits from its history. Do you want that?

Comment: here is my [git rev-list --first-parent](https://i.imgur.com/2fRtQFD.jpg), here is my plain [git rev-list](https://i.imgur.com/dpg3rQS.jpg) Same thing happens. Empty commits with duplicated descriptions show up. Commit descriptions are not representative of their content. Now there are two commits that do nothing. Tracking changes in code is compromised. I see them in `git log` as well.

Comment: @Nomenator I don't see what happen when you merge, can't tell why. But this is definitely not normal merge. With a normal merge you can be sure to see difference when `git rev-list` with `--first-parent`. I've just tested on my local machine, same as I expected.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining. These were just two pull requests, one with the first two commits, the second as shown in screenshot. I'm not sure if this is how Azure handles pull requests that makes it different. Either way, your instruction was very helpful, I dove a bit deeper into the structure of git repository and I'll work on refining the branching strategy for the project in order to keep the history clean.